# recyclerview doesn't display items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I made acustom list item to show in recyclerview
Just one only item show in this recycle

[image]

> MainActivity

```
 AdapterforRecycleview adapter  = new AdapterforRecycleview(this,dataItemList);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

> Adapter 
>   [image]
>   [image]

Comment: Log ? What happend?

Comment: You also need to set a LayoutManager

Comment: I made it in Xml but one item only show just one !

Comment: please post xml code for recyclerview items

Comment: @ِAalap Patal  thanks it solved

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `listitem.xml` make sure you set

don't forget to add layout manager

in XML:         `app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"`
or

app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager"

or in code:

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

or

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, 2));
```

Comment: thanks for helping :"D

Comment: i don't see the difference. lol

Answer (score 5):

You should also add `LayoutManager` to the `recyclerView`.

```
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
```

and if you have made it in XML please refer below:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager" >
```

> The class must extend
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutManager and have either a
>   default constructor or constructor with the signature
>   (android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int, int).
>
> If the name starts with a '.', application package is prefixed. Else,
>   if the name contains a '.', the classname is assumed to be a full
>   class name. Else, the recycler view package name
>   (android.support.v7.widget) is prefixed.

i hope it helps.

Comment: I made it in Xml but one item only show just one !

Comment: check the edited answer. @AmmArYasser

Comment: @AmmArYasser also check if in  R.layout.lisstitem, height is wrap_content or match_parent.

Comment: Thank u it solved

Comment: do upvote the solution and mark it accepted for others too. thanks @AmmAr